# Whats the best way to format this number?

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I have a `double` and I want to format it with the following rules:

1. If there are no decimal places show just the number  (see 100 example below)
2. If there are any decimal places show 2 decimal places

So, as a few examples:

```
100 --> 100  
99.958443534 --> 99.96  
99.1 -> 99.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
decimal a = 99.949999999M;

Math.Round(a, 2);  // Returns 99.95
```

Comment: He wants 28 to return 28, not 28.00

Comment: @Neil Knight - that is NOT what i want.  as stated if there are NO decimals in the number, i dont want to show the ".00"

Answer (score 4):

You could check if its a whole number, the use the type of formatting based on that:

```
string res = string.Format(((number % 1) == 0) ? "{0:0}" : "{0:0.00}", number);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var a = 100;
var b = 99.95844354;

var aAnswer = a.ToString("0.##"); //aAnswer is "100"
var bAnswer = b.ToString("0.##"); //bAnswer is "99.96"
```

Comment: This would work if there is always two decimal places.  If the OP has 1.2, then I think they expect the result to be 1.20.  This would result in 1.2